# Cookies shared by wildcard certificate and a site-specific certificate on different CAs?

Tags: javascript, ssl, cookies, ssl-certificate, wildcard

Here's our situation (sanitized):

- We have a wildcard certificate for *.foo.com -- CA is "Primary CA"
- We are considering adding a vendor's SaaS.  Our requirements state the vendor SaaS site URL should be bar.foo.com.
- While we could issue a separate wildcard certificate *.foo.com from "Primary CA" specifically for this vendor's SaaS site, the vendor at this time is not ready to support hosting that separate wildcard certificate.  Instead, the vendor will themselves arrange for a site-specific SSL certificate for bar.foo.com -- quite potentially from a CA other than "Primary CA".
- Our current concept is to pass information between two sites using cookies as well as JavaScript calls:

  - www.foo.com with the above-mentioned wildcard certificate from "Primary CA"
  - bar.foo.com with the vendor-provided site-specific SSL certificate -- most likely from another CA

Questions:

- In theory, bar.foo.com should be covered by the wildcard certificate.  Will this cause browsers to reject the vendor-provided site-specific certificate for bar.foo.com?
- Given the certificates for www.foo.com and bar.foo.com will be coming from two CAs, will we be able to pass cookies and use JavaScript calls between the two sites without browsers complaining about cross-site problems, same-origin problems, etc.?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have Wildcard SSL certificate for *.foo.com so you don't require to take separate wildcard SSL certificate or an SSL certificate for bar.foo.com because the existing certificate will cover bar.foo.com (sub domain). Whatever the server is, Wildcard SSL certificate gives unlimited server license.

Comment: Our vendor at this time will not use any SSL certificate we send them; they will generate and use a site-specific SSL certificate from their preferred CA for bar.foo.com.  So www.foo.com (protected by wildcard certificate *.foo.com from our CA) and bar.foo.com (protected by the site-specific certificate from their CA) communicating data through cookies and/or JavaScript.  Is that going to work without browsers complaining about cross-site problems, same-origin problems, etc.?